# Method is returning false but conditions match and should be returning true

Tags: java, foreach, while-loop, enums

i currently have some User objects that have a type enum enumUserType but one of them has a enumUserType of LIBRARIAN. The users who are librarian need to have special privileges, in this case it will have a different menu it can access.

What i have tried to do loop through an array list of users and if that user has a usertype of librarian then return true, if it is something else return false.

After some testing it seems like that even if just one of my objects is librarian then entire method will return true. Then i cant lead the different usertypes down the different menu paths.
My first object isnt a librarian but the second one is.

```
public boolean verifyLibrarian() {
    for (User s : users) {
    //if just one of my objects is librarian it will return true.
        if (s.getUserType() == User.enumUserType.LIBRARIAN) {
            return true;
         }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
     }
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Username or password is 
       incorrect");

}
```

Here is my while loop aswell:

```
while(exit == 0)
    {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your user name");
        String userName = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your password name");
        String passWord = scanner.nextLine();


         if (library.verifyLogin(userName, passWord)== true && library.verifyLibrarian() != true)
            {
                this.currentLoginUser = userName;
                mainMenuAfterLogin();
            }
   //because my method is returning true, even logged in non librarians 
       //will get lead down to this menu
         else if(library.verifyLogin(userName, passWord) == true && 
         library.verifyLibrarian() == true)
         {
                this.currentLoginUser = userName;
                librarianMenuEditBook();

         }
    }
```

Let me know if you need more information.
Thank you kindly for you help.

Comment: `for (User s : users) {` this loop will only be iterated once

Comment: and in your first iteration: it's not a Librarian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `return false` outside the loop to check against every user before returning false

```
for (User s : users) {
//if just one of my objects is librarian it will return true.
    if (s.getUserType() == User.enumUserType.LIBRARIAN) {
        return true;
     }    
}
return false;
```

Or use anyMatch

```
return users.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.getUserType() == User.enumUserType.LIBRARIAN);
```

If your intention was to really throw an exception if no user was found (currently that's unreachable in your code, you'd throw that instead of returning

```
public boolean verifyLibrarian() {
    for (User s : users) {
    //if just one of my objects is librarian it will return true.
        if (s.getUserType() == User.enumUserType.LIBRARIAN) {
            return true;
        }    
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Username or password is incorrect");
}
```

Or in a stream

```
users.stream()
      .filter(s -> s.getUserType() == User.enumUserType.LIBRARIAN)
      .findAny()
      .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Username or password is incorrect"));
```

Comment: hey mate thanks for the comment, i am still getting the same issue though, its false if they both aren't librarians but true if any of them is a librarian. I tried both solutions you posted.

Comment: Yes, if any is liberian above returns true. Do you want to check if all are liberians instead? @awyeanah2

Comment: i ended up fixing it, i filtered the results with a parameter in verifylibrarian(username) so if username equaled the username in the array list and they were a librarian return true.
Thank you for your help leading me in the right direction.